# can we load deleted contacts' data from contacts content provider?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

hello~ when we delete contacts in android, android just sets raw_contacts.deleted=1. All data of the deleted contact can be found in the table "data" by SQLiteAdmin or other tools.
I want to load these deleted contacts' data, but it doesn't work.codes are as foloowed:

```
    private void restoreContactsData() {
    Uri idUri=Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts");
    Uri dataUri=Uri.parse("content://"+ContactsContract.AUTHORITY+"/data");
    Cursor c=cr.query(idUri, new String[]{"_id"}, "deleted=1", null, null);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        int deletedRawContactId=c.getInt(0);
        sb.append("rawId="+deletedRawContactId).append("\n\t");
        Cursor dataCursor=cr.query(dataUri, 
                    new String[]{"data1"},
                    "row_contact_id="+deletedRawContactId, 
                    null, 
                    null);
            while(dataCursor.moveToNext()){
                String phone=dataCursor.getString(0);
                sb.append(phone).append("\n");
            }
        }
    tv.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

I have tried to set the constant VISIBLE_CONTACTS_ONLY=false as parameter,but i wont' work either.

The method above can find the deleted raw_contact ids.BUT when I use these ids to query the "data" table , it return nothing. 
If I pull the contacts2.db file out of emulator, I can find the data which are associated with the deleted raw_contact in the "data" table.

The question is ,whether can i restore these deleted data from contacts' contentprovider?
Thank you